# Create Login and User via T-SQL for linked servers

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server

I would like to make a Stored Procedure that can create MSSQL Login and User for both local server and linked server, with Check Policy is OFF.

I have no problem to create login and user in local server with CREATE LOGIN and CREATE USER, but I have no idea how to use CREATE LOGIN and CREATE USER for linked server.

I have tried to use sp_addlogin and sp_adduser for linked server, but with Password Policy failed.

Is there any way to run CREATE LOGIN and CREATE USER in linked servers? Below is my code in dynamic SQL.

```
SELECT @SqlCreateLogin = 'USE '+ @dbDatabase + ';
    CREATE LOGIN [' + @loginName + '] 
    WITH PASSWORD = '''+@password+''',
    DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], 
    DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english],
    CHECK_POLICY=OFF'   
EXEC sp_executesql @SqlCreateLogin


SELECT @SqlCreateUser = 
    'USE ' + @dbDatabase + ';
    CREATE USER [' + @loginName + '] FOR LOGIN [' + @loginName +']'
EXEC sp_executesql @SqlCreateUser
```

Comment: Create a stored procedure on the remote server with code to create the login and execute it. Too much or security risk otherwise.

Comment: The current design is using one main server to control the login to different remote servers. The current task is to centralize the creation of the login and user processing by the main server. Is the creation of stored procedure on the remote server and execute in the main server the only solution?

Comment: I do believe so. You might check at the http://dba.stackexchange.com/ for more ideas though.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved a similar case. The linked server is passed dynamically too. Be carefull with the quotes:

```
    DECLARE @query nvarchar(1000)
    SET @query = 'EXEC (''CREATE LOGIN [' + @user + '] WITH PASSWORD=N''''' +
        @password + ''''', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF,
        CHECK_POLICY=OFF'') AT [' + @linkedserver + ']'
    EXEC sp_Executesql @query
```

Similar for add user and role:

```
    SET @query = 'EXEC (''USE [' + @database + '];CREATE USER [' + 
        @user + '] FOR LOGIN [' + @user + ']'') AT [' + @linkedserver + ']'

    SET @query = 'EXEC (''USE [' + @database + '];ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] 
    ADD MEMBER [' + @user + ']'') AT [' + @linkedserver + ']'
```